# Xamarin/Android webview hide website element/class

Tags: webview, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a little android app showing a webview loading a website.
I got it to show it with the following code snippets. But what I need now is to hide some elements on the header and the footer(a menu for example). I thought I could do it not loading some classes from the webpage, but I'm not sure how to properly do it. Do anyone have some experience on this to share some light? :)

Thanks in advance.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {


            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            fab.Click += FabOnClick;

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            wbv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
            wbv.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendWebViewClient());
            WebSettings webSettings = wbv.Settings;
            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            wbv.LoadUrl(txtUrl);


        }

internal class ExtendWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
              {

                view.LoadUrl(url);
                return true;
              }
        }
```

edit: Just to reflect the changes to the second class

```
public class ExtendWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
             string js = "var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName('fusion-main-menu');" +
              " myElements[0].style.display = 'none'; ";
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                view.EvaluateJavascript(js, null);
            }
            else
            {
                view.LoadUrl(js);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have enabled javascript, there will be a function to run the script in the webview.

This is the code of WebView using Xamarin.Forms.WebView and this is how you can hide any element of webview using it's id.

```
 var hide = await webview.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('UserName').style.display = 'none';");
```

Comment: Edited the original question to reflect the changes on the second class based on your suggestion. It's loading the webview just fine but it's somehow ignoring the js command. If I execute it on the webpage console it hides the element. It's xamarin.android by the way, if it changes anything. Do you know what can I be doing wrong? Had to change your suggested code sightly to adequate to my code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Nevermind, it was my bad. I was trying to find the wrong class. Thanks.

Comment: That is why I mentioned that the webview is of Xamarin Forms to give you the idea what you really need. You're welcome :)